# What's the equivalent of rake routes in Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

Ruby on Rails comes with the terminal command `rake routes`. Is there an equivalent in Phoenix?

Comment: It's in official documentation in the first steps...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command is `$ mix phoenix.routes`

Comment: per below this is `mix phx.routes`

Answer (score 4):

As @Martimatix pointed out `$ mix phx.routes` print all routes for the default router, here's the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Routes.html#content)

This is an example of routes generated for this `router.ex` file:

```
defmodule MessageApi.Router do
  use MessageApi.Web, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/api", MessageApi do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/messages", MessageController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/message_details", MessageDetailController, except: [:new, :edit]

  end
end
```

then routes generated will be:

```
       message_path  GET     /api/messages             MessageApi.MessageController :index
       message_path  GET     /api/messages/:id         MessageApi.MessageController :show
       message_path  POST    /api/messages             MessageApi.MessageController :create
       message_path  PATCH   /api/messages/:id         MessageApi.MessageController :update
                     PUT     /api/messages/:id         MessageApi.MessageController :update
       message_path  DELETE  /api/messages/:id         MessageApi.MessageController :delete
message_detail_path  GET     /api/message_details      MessageApi.MessageDetailController :index
message_detail_path  GET     /api/message_details/:id  MessageApi.MessageDetailController :show
message_detail_path  POST    /api/message_details      MessageApi.MessageDetailController :create
message_detail_path  PATCH   /api/message_details/:id  MessageApi.MessageDetailController :update
                     PUT     /api/message_details/:id  MessageApi.MessageDetailController :update
message_detail_path  DELETE  /api/message_details/:id  MessageApi.MessageDetailController :delete
```